# How to configure action on plugging in an usb MTP device on windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, android, mtp

There is one thing that bugs me.

I have an Nexus 4 (Kitkat) and an Windows 8.1 device. Every time I connect the phone via usb (MTP) the windows explorer opens.

This me be fine for others but in most cases I just want to charge my phone. Even worse, my cable or nexus has a loose contact and often when I take my phone to look for notifications the explorer pops up again.

Is there a way to disable the auto open explorer function in windows? I still want to be able to use the storage so disabling file transfer is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out already

`Computer Configuration / Administrative Templates / Windows Components / Autoplay Polices`

The setting is `Disallow Autoplay for Non-Volume devices` and should be set to `Enabled`